# how to get value of textview from alertview

Tags: ios, textview, alertview

i can't get the value of textView from my alertView

```
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 50, 260, 100)];

    [textView setText:@""];

    UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"put text\n\n\n\n\n\n" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Annuler" otherButtonTitles:@"Envoyer",nil];
    av.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleDefault;
    [av addSubview:textView];
    [av show];
```

it display alertview view with textview inside and its fine, i want to get the value of textview i my

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {        
}
```

can you help me please

Comment: you can use with the help of tag

Comment: This may be of help to you: In iOS 5 there is a standardised `UIAlertView` complete with a textbox for basic input. Just set the style like so: `alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;`. You can then extract what the user has entered like so: `- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{ 
    NSLog(@"Entered: %@",[[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] text]);
}` [Found here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319417/whats-a-simple-way-to-get-a-text-input-popup-dialog-box-on-an-iphone).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare textView for use throughout your class

```
@implementation objectTables
{
    UITextView *textView;
}
```

then in your

```
textView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 50, 260, 100)];

    [textView setText:@""];

    UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Push Notification\n\n\n\n\n\n" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Annuler" otherButtonTitles:@"Envoyer",nil];
    av.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleDefault;
    [av addSubview:textView];
    [av show];
```

and

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {     

   NSString *textViewText = [textView text];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use **- (UITextField *)textFieldAtIndex:(NSInteger)textFieldIndex**  which will return object of **UITextField**.

and from **UITextField** get text from it.

Or another way is

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{


UITextField *TextField = (UITextField *)[alertView viewWithTag:YOURTAG];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 50, 260, 100)];
[textView setText:@""];
textView.tag = 10;
UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"put text\n\n\n\n\n\n" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Annuler" otherButtonTitles:@"Envoyer",nil];
av.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleDefault;
[av addSubview:textView];
[av show];
```

In Delegate

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
      UITextView *textView = (UITextView *) [alertView viewWithTag:10];
      NSString *yourText = textView.text;       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Declare Your `UITextView` in .h File

```
UITextView *textView;
```

and in .m file

```
textView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 50, 260, 100)];

    [textView setText:@""];

    UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"put text\n\n\n\n\n\n" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Annuler" otherButtonTitles:@"Envoyer",nil];
    av.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleDefault;
    [av addSubview:textView];
    [av show];

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex 
{
//Gives you the Value of UITextView
        NSLog(@"%@",[textView text]); 
}
```

Or you can define it as the property in `Extended class`(.m file) and access it.

```
@Interface yourINterfaceName()
{
@property(nonatomic , retain ) UITextView *textView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 50, 260, 100)];

[textView setText:@""];
textView.tag =10;
UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"put text\n\n\n\n\n\n" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Annuler" otherButtonTitles:@"Envoyer",nil];
av.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleDefault;
[av addSubview:textView];
[av show];



- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{

 UITextView *textView = (UITextView *)[alertView viewWithTag:10];
  NSLog(@"%@",[textView text]); 

}
```