# How to add a Label and Textfield to the alertview in ios 7

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I have a problem with `UIAlertview` in `ios7`,

In my application i have multiple `labels` and `textfileds` in `uialerview`. I tried in ios5 and 6 its working fine but in ios7 its not showing label and `textfileds`.

please any one help me

Comment: Did you do any research?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to add UITextField to UIAlertView on iOS7...works in iOS 6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18549519/unable-to-add-uitextfield-to-uialertview-on-ios7-works-in-ios-6)

Answer (score 2):

You can set the style of your alert :

```
alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
```

This code will add a text field on the UIAlertView.
And you can access it in the UIAlertView delegate callback by using

```
UITextField *textField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
```

But, since iOS 7, UIAlertView's contentView property are removed. Have a look [here](http://blog.manbolo.com/2013/08/05/uialertviews-contentview-property-removed-from-ios-7).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I tried this one but i want Label as well as textfield, if i use the above code i will get only one textfield. but i want multiple labels and textfields.

Comment: So you can't now with iOS 7. Sorry.
You need to create your own UIAlertView or Custom View

Comment: alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;  If we use this one we will get one textfield, so how to get that textfield length.