# alertview closes when another alert appears

Tags: ios, delegates, uialertview, alertview

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"......" message:@"......" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];

[alert show];
```

I am showing alert view to add a new category using through text field of alert view, when user tapes ok button of alert then I first check that if user has entered anything or not, if not then I show another alert with some message to let user know that text field is mandatory, but previous alert for adding new category disappears.

I want that alert to stay on the screen.
So what Should I do ??

This is the crash report and code::

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Add Vehicle Category" message:@"this gets covered!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
            alert.tag = 5;

txtAddVehicleCategory = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 45, 260, 25)];

[txtAddVehicleCategory setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

txtAddVehicleCategory.placeholder = @"Enter Vehicle Category";

txtAddVehicleCategory.contentVerticalAlignment =       UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;

[alert addSubview:txtAddVehicleCategory];


CGAffineTransform myTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -50);

[alert setTransform:myTransform];

[alert show];
```

'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'textFieldIndex (0) is outside of the bounds of the array of text fields'

Comment: Just so you know, from iOS7 onwards, this code will not work. So if you are planning to submit to AppStore, I would look for a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to implement some rules for entering text in `UIAlertView`, you should disable the `OK` button of your alert view until user follows the rules. You can achieve this with `UIAlertViewDelegate` methods. Look into [`alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007548-CH3-SW6).

Return `NO` from the method until rule is followed

```
- (BOOL)alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton:(UIAlertView *)alertView
{
    // When return NO, OK button is disabled.
    // When return YES, rule is followed and OK button gets enabled.
    return ([[[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] text] length]>0)?YES:NO;
}
```

---

**EDIT**

The code that I provided was assuming you are using default alert view style textfield, hence the crash.

You should not `addSubview` to `UIAlertView`, because the view hierarchy of alert view is private. Most recent [iOS7 will not display any subviews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18549519/unable-to-add-uitextfield-to-uialertview-on-ios7-works-in-ios-6) that user adds on `UIAlertView`.So I recommend you do not do this.

From [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIAlertViewStyle),

> The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.

Instead, use `UIAlertViewStyle`.

Following are the styles supported,

```
typedef enum {
   UIAlertViewStyleDefault = 0,
   UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput,
   UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput,
   UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput
} UIAlertViewStyle;
```

Use the one that suits your requirement. To validate the input entered by the user use the above method that I suggested. Refer [this simple guide/tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-5-sdk-uialertview-text-input-and-validation/) for using the alert view with these styles.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Using your solution my app gets crashed when the button is tapped to open alert view

Comment: @ParasGorasiya Add your code and crash report in the question.

Comment: I have updated my code and added crash report and code for calling alert.

Comment: Thanks for this info but I can't use this solution because of certain requirements, so please provide any other solution.

Comment: @ParasGorasiya This is the recommended way. But if this does not meet your requirements you can implement a custom alert view, or use any open source. [TSAlertView](https://github.com/mindbrix/TSAlertView), [ios-custom-alertview](https://github.com/wimagguc/ios-custom-alertview) are few options. I will still stress not to do `addSubview` on `UIAlertView`.