# Entering Text Using Pop-up in IOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

I have an app that was built on Xcode 4.6 and iOS 6. I am now upgrading it to iOS 7 using XCode 5.

I have this code that worked perfectly on iOS 6. What it does it bring a popup with UITextField in it. User can enter whatever text they want and hit OK. I take their text and put it in a UILabel.

The problem I have is that in iOS 7 when I bring up this pop-up text box, its not editable. Touching it doesn't do anything. How come?

Here is the code and screenshot

```
// ************ 
// ENTER TEXT
// ************

-(IBAction)insertText 
{
    UIAlertView* dialog = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Enter Text \n"
                                                     message:@"\n\n Keep it short and sweet"   
                                                    delegate:self 
                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                           otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];

    nameField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0, 45.0, 245.0, 25.0)];
    [nameField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [dialog addSubview:nameField];
    [dialog show];
}
```

[image]

Comment: For future reference - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319417/whats-a-simple-way-to-get-a-text-input-popup-dialog-box-on-an-iphone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the provided API instead this hack. Instead of adding your own text field (which was never actually supported), set the alert view's `alertViewStyle` to `UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput`. This will give you a supported text entry field in the alert view.

Comment: To complete this answer: The hack isn't working because iOS 7 does *not* support adding subviews to UIAlertView. But iOS 6 did.

Comment: `UIAlertView` never supported subviews. It just happen to work in earlier versions of iOS. There is a difference.

Comment: UIAlertView inherits from UIView. UIView supports addSubview:. So UIAlertView supports addSubview: as long as it doesn't prevent you from using it. Of course it wasn't officially supported (meaning documented by Apple), but it was supported.

Comment: Just because it is based on `UIView` doesn't mean you are supposed to add subviews. Most of the standard UI components provided by Apple are not supposed to have subviews added to them and you should never rely on the subview structure. These things change. Stick to the API provided and you avoid problems like this question.

Comment: You're can never completely avoid changing your code when a new iOS version comes out - even if you stick to the API. Remember iOS 6 when we all had to change the way we implement display rotation? We all sticked to the API and Apple changed it. I never said it was a good idea to completely change the look of Apple provided views, but it isn't forbidden until it works technically.