# Users input in textfield to array

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm completely new to Xcode and not very good at programming in general. So plz be nice!

I'm making a little game where a label updates, so a challenge will appear every time you push a button. I've done that with a switch-case.

I want another little feature to this game, where the user can type whatever challenge they want in a textfield, where the textfield writes to an array or something. The new challenges has to be added as cases in the switch-case-part, so when the user pushes the 'get challenge'-button, the user might get their own challenge.

I had tried a lot of things, but nothing is working out for me, so I just wondered, if any of you had a complete answer? My problem is marked with '//Here is where my problem is. Any suggestions?' in the .m .

I'm sorry if someone else had asked a simular question before. I just couldn't find it.

Also, I had some trouble finding the right title for this question?

Thank you!

```
//  ViewController.h



#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *GetChallenge;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *ShowChallenge;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *AddNewChallenge;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *AddNewButton;



@end
```

and

```
//  ViewController.m

#import "ViewController.h"


@implementation ViewController
@synthesize GetChallenge;
@synthesize ShowChallenge;
@synthesize AddNewChallenge;
@synthesize AddNewButton;







- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


}



- (IBAction)AddNewButton:(id)sender {





    // Here is where my problem is. Any suggestions?
    // Here is where my problem is. Any suggestions?
    // Here is where my problem is. Any suggestions?
    // Here is where my problem is. Any suggestions?
    // Here is where my problem is. Any suggestions?




}




- (IBAction)GetChallenge:(id)sender {

    int text = rand() %93;


    switch (text) {
        case 0:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"a!";
            break;
        case 1:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"b!";
            break;
        case 2:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"c!";
            break;
        case 3:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"d";
            break;
        case 4:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"e!";
            break;
        case 6:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"f";
            break;
        case 7:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"g";
            break;
        case 8:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"h";
            break;
        case 9:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"i";
            break;
        case 10:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"j";
            break;
        case 11:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"k";
            break;
        case 12:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"l";
            break;
        case 13:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"m";
            break;
        case 14:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"n!";
            break;
        case 15:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"o";
            break;
        case 16:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"p";
            break;
        case 17:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"q";
            break;
        case 18:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"r";
            break;
        case 19:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"s";
            break;
        case 20:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"t";
            break;
        case 21:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"u";
            break;
        case 22:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"'v";
            break;
        case 23:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"'w";
            break;
        case 24:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"'x";
            break;
        case 25:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"'y";
            break;
        case 26:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"z";
            break;
        case 27:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"aa";
            break;
        case 28:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"bb";
            break;
        case 29:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"cc";
            break;
        case 30:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"dd";
            break;
        case 31:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"ee";
            break;
        case 32:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"ff";
            break;
        case 33:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"'gg!";
            break;
        case 34:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"'hh";
            break;
        case 35:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"ii";
            break;
        case 36:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"jj";
            break;
        case 37:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"kk";
            break;
        case 38:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"ll";
            break;
        case 39:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"mm";
            break;
        case 40:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"nn";
            break;
        case 41:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"oo!";
            break;
        case 42:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"pp";
            break;
        case 43:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"qq";
            break;
        case 44:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"rr";
            break;
        case 45:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"ss";
            break;
        case 46:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"tt";
            break;
        case 47:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"uu";
            break;
        case 48:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"vv";
            break;
        case 49:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"ww";
            break;


            //cartgame

        case 50:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"aaa";
            break;
        case 51:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"bbb!";
            break;
        case 52:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"ccc";
            break;
        case 53:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"ddd!";
            break;
        case 54:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"eee!";
            break;
        case 55:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"fff";
            break;
        case 56:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"ggg";
            break;
        case 57:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"hhh!";
            break;
        case 58:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"iii";
            break;
        case 59:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"jjj";
            break;
        case 60:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"kkk";
            break;
        case 61:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"lll";
            break;
        case 62:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"mmm";
            break;
        case 63:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"nnn";
            break;
        case 64:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"ooo";
            break;
        case 65:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"ppp";
            break;
        case 66:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"qqq";
            break;
        case 67:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"sss";
            break;
        case 68:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"ttt";
            break;
        case 69:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"uuu";
            break;
        case 70:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"vvv";
            break;
        case 71:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"www";
            break;
        case 72:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"xxx";
            break;
        case 73:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"yyy";
            break;
        case 74:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"zzz";
            break;
        case 75:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"aaaa";
            break;
        case 76:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"bbbb";
            break;
        case 77:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"cccc";
            break;
        case 78:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"dddd";
            break;
        case 79:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"eeee";
            break;
        case 80:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"ffff!";
            break;
        case 81:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"gggg!";
            break;
        case 82:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"hhhh";
            break;
        case 83:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"iiii";
            break;
        case 84:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"jjjj!";
            break;
        case 85:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"kkkk!";
            break;
        case 86:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"llll!";
            break;
        case 87:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"mmmm!";
            break;
        case 88:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"nnnn!";
            break;
        case 89:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"oooo";
            break;


        case 90:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"pppp";
            break;
        case 91:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"qqqq!";
            break;
        case 92:
            ShowChallenge.text = @"rrrr!";
            break;



        default:
            break;
    }




}



// Goodbye keyboard

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [AddNewChallenge resignFirstResponder];

}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (textField){
        [AddNewChallenge resignFirstResponder];
    }
        return NO;

}





- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}





@end
```

Thanks again!

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319417/whats-a-simple-way-to-get-a-text-input-popup-dialog-box-on-an-iphone

Comment: ok bro.. this is just.. not right.. if you want to have a talk about it.. add me on skype: mrpatrnogic

Comment: I want to have a text box where the user can write a challenge and add it to a group of other challenges that's already in the game by clicking on a button. The problem is that I don't know how that is done :)

Yea, it may seem pretty clear that I need a little help!
Thank you again. 
I've send you a friend request.

Answer (score 0):

First I would suggest putting all the challenges into an array. It will make your code a lot cleaner, easier to read and easier to maintain.

Then you can simply add the user's challenge to the array.

When it comes to randomly selecting the challenge you can simply do:

```
int text = rand() % array.count;

//Check the value is a valid index:

if (text >= 0 && <= (array.count - 1))
{
  ShowChallenge.text = array[text];
}
```

Comment: I thought it might was better to use an array, but it was working with the switch case, so I just thought it was fine.

I'm sorry for being such a newbie, but it's not working with your suggestion. It gets the warning: "Use of undeclared identifier 'array'" next to each line of code in your suggestion. How to fix that? 

Thank you so much - I hope this is not to much trouble for you guys! ;)

Comment: You need to declare the array first. e.g NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];